# Bond agreggation

Tags: bond, asset-pricing, asset

I'm working on an asset and liabilities model for life insurance as a school project, one of the inputs of the model is a bond portfolio, for the sake of optimization of computation speed (the model also uses an economic scenario generator to evaluate the portfolio in multiple scenarios) i thought that aggregating the bond portfolio might help.

What i mean by aggregating is that instead of having a line by line bond database i would create an "equivalent" portfolio made with zero coupons giving (approximately at least) the same cashflows. Do you know any technique to do is, for example how should redistribute the capital gains(Market Value-Book Value) of the non-agreggated portfolio to the aggregated one?

Thank you.

Comment: Take an ETF: US AGG ETF e.g.

Comment: @DataAdventurer doesnt seem like a solution to my problem..? Asset and liabilities models project future cashflows on thousands of economic scenarios, what i'm looking for is: for a yearly time step can i replace my 3 000 lines of a real company portfolio of bonds with a surrogate portfolio of lets say 30 zero coupons? the n-th zero coupon would give the cashflow of the n-th year of the real 3000 lines portfolio